# asp.net, wcf authentication and caching

Tags: asp.net, wcf, session, caching, authentication

I need to place my app business logic into a WCF service. The service shouldn't be dependent on ASP.NET and there is a lot of data regarding the authenticated user which is frequently used in the business logic hence it's supposed to be cached (probably using a distributed cache). As for authentication - I'm going to use two level authentication:

1. Front-End  - forms authentication back-end
2. (WCF Service) - message username authentication.

For both authentications the same custom membership provider is supposed to be used.
To cache the authenticated user data, I'm going to implement two service methods:

1) Authenticate - will retrieve the needed data and place it into the cache(where username will be used as a key)
2) SignOut - will remove the data from the cache

**Question 1. Is correct to perform authentication that way (in two places) ?**

**Question 2. Is this caching strategy worth using or should I look at using aspnet compatible service and asp.net session ?**

Maybe, these questions are too general. But, anyway I'd like to get any suggestions or recommendations.

Any Idea

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1:**

From my experience the ASP forms authentication would be enough. No reason to send credentials as POST and certainly not GET. You can use that for a change password or account info method.  You might want to look into Membership and Roles.

**Question 2:**

I would stick with the ASP.NET session.  This might make your application more prone to issues and vulnerabilities in the end, and I see it as unnecessary.

Comment: But session will expire after application recycle and cache duration will be as set by you.

Comment: If you don't want to lost data after application recycle, you can use SQL server. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Answer (score 1):

Passing the password to between the services is not a good practice. You should consider [creating a custom security token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731872%28VS.90%29.aspx) in your front-end application and passing this token to the WCF service. WCF service can validate the token using a certificate. With this approach  you can

- insert any user data into the security token and use in the WCF service
- cache the token in the front-end application session, therefore you don't need any distributed cache
- centralize login and avoid authenticating user twice

Comment: Thanks, rosencreuz. This is a really useful info. But, I'm wondering what's bad in passing the password to the service?

Comment: Password is confidential information, you need to secure it. Best practice is to do the authentication as early as possible so that you don't need to care about it in all applications. For instance, most likely you don't want to encrypt your internal traffic (SSL) between frontend and WCF service, you don't want to do security audit for password handling in WCF service, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be dependant on ASP.NET then you shouldn't use any session

What I could advice:

1. Use a UserNameValidator, so that you need to send username/password on each request to the wcf service (there are a lot of article on the web on how to configure a UserNameValidator)
2. Implement an IAuthorizationPolicy where you can retrieve user data to set the roles etc. This object is created once then reused

The problem is that if you only use these 2 components, you'll need to fetch the data for each request as you've no way to transfert the username from the UserNameValidator to the IAuthorizationPolicy
To avoid that, you'll need to implement the complete authentication mechanism in WCF. It's not hard at all, and here is a very nice link that help me to do it in 1 or 2 hours:

http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user.aspx

The "PasswordAuthorizationPolicy" (in the link above) is created once, then reused. And for each request the Evaluate method is called.

It means that you can add any custom property on this class, fill them in the constructor, and then use them forever. You don't need to manage this cache lifetime as it's binded to the client channel, so once the client close the connection the channel will expire all these data will be removed from memory

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create class **Authentication** (or something else) on WCF side:

```
public class Authentication<T>
{
    public static Dictionary<string, T> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And if you have User class:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You can manage users like this:

```
Authentication<User>.Users.Add("username", new User());
```